# Can't find exported subroutine in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a module called `Utilities.pm`.  It exports a subroutine called `dummy_method`.

```
package Foo::Utilities;

use strict;
use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT @EXPORT_OK);

require Exporter;

@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(dummy_method);

sub dummy_method {
  # do things
}
```

I have a Perl script that uses the `dummy_method` subroutine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Foo::Utilities qw('dummy_method');

my $foo = Foo::Utilities::dummy_method("foo");
print("$foo\n");
```

Executing that script throws an export error:

> "dummy_method" is not exported by the Foo::Utilities module
>   Can't continue after import errors at /home/me/foo.pl line 3
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/me/foo.pl line 3.

I'm confused because I am explicitly exporting that subroutine with `@EXPORT = qw(dummy_method);`.  How do I use `dummy_method` in another script?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Your module exports `dummy_method` but you are trying to import and run `some_method` which doesn't even exist. Note that, once you have imported a subroutine correctly, you don't need to qualify it fully: `some_method('foo')` will be fine.

Comment: @Borodin It was a typo - this is fixed.

Comment: I wish you would copy and paste your real code and errors.

Comment: what Borodin said.  You have changed the error message in an important way.  Or else changed the code.  We can't tell for sure.  Always always always copy and paste your actual code and errors.

Comment: @Borodin I didn't make the error message up.

Comment: @alex   Yes, you did. I doubt if the original message contained *either* `some_method` or `dummy_method`. It certainly can't be correct both before and after you modified it.

Comment: @Borodin Respectfully speaking - I did not, although I did obfuscate the method name and my home directory path.  I wanted to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so my question was not closed as off-topic.  I think you suspect that there is a simple typographical error in my actual code, because there was a typo in my question. I can assure you that this is not the case and that I performed multiple sanity checks before posting the question.

Comment: *"I did obfuscate the method name"*  That involves making stuff up.  *"I wanted to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example"* That's laudable, but it involves writing code that produces the same error, and then *copying and pasting that exact code* into your question. Your code generates `"'dummy_method'" is not exported by the Foo::Utilities module` which is very different from the message that you show. Furthermore, there is no error at all when the fix from ***ysth*** is made, and I can only imagine that you have named your module file incorrectly as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, it's made it up but it shouldn't matter in this case. `/s/dummy_method/actual_subroutine_name/` - the problem should persist.  As for the error, I can assure you that this is the exact same error that I copy/pasted from STDOUT - I just changed the `actual_subroutine_name` to `dummy_method`.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @alex: You're misunderstanding me. You should be creating an *MCVE*, including any name changes that you want to make, that displays the same problem as your main code when you run it. Then you post that code together with the messages that it generates. What you have done seems to be to type in something that you think should do the same thing, making an error with the subroutine identifier, and posted an edited version of the original error message with the name changed incorrectly. I doubt if you've even tried to run your "MCVE" and that completely spoils the point.

Comment: @alex: *"this is the exact same error that I copy/pasted from STDOUT - I just changed the `actual_subroutine_name` to `dummy_method`"* Yes, but I imagine it's the edited output from your real code. What you have shown in your question does something different, so it's not an MCVE and frankly it's useless for diagnosing the issue.

Comment: @Borodin As a follow-up, the issue ended up actually being that multiple  `Foo::Utilities` modules were being referenced by my `$PERL5LIB` environmental variable. The one that did not have the `dummy_method` subroutine was taking precedence over the one that I updated - so the error message that I posted was technically true, but indeed misleading, as the problem was an environmental issue.  I appreciate your help with this issue.

Comment: You should add export tags of all to export all: `our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( all  => [ @EXPORT, @EXPORT_OK ] );` Then one could get all the exports with: `use Utilities ':all';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have written, with the modification suggested by ***ysth***, works correctly. The only remaining possibility that I can think of is that you have named or located your module incorrectly

```
use Foo::Utilities 'dummy_method'
```

will load a file called `Foo/Utilities.pm` where the `Foo` directory is in one of the paths in your `@INC`. It is a common error to omit the initial directories that must be in the path to the module, and you do say that your module is called just `Utilities.pm`

There must also be a `Foo/Utilities.pm` that behaves differently, otherwise the `use` statement would fail even to find the file

I have written your code in more modern Perl. This also works

#### Foo/Utilities.pm

```
package Foo::Utilities;

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Exporter 'import';

our @EXPORT = qw(dummy_method);

sub dummy_method {
  print "dummy_method()\n";
  'do things';
}
```

#### main.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Foo::Utilities 'dummy_method';

my $foo = dummy_method('foo');

print("$foo\n");
```

There is no need for using `vars` any more, and it has been better to *import* the `import` method from `Exporter` (instead of inheriting it) since Perl v5.8.7

Comment: *There must also be a Foo/Utilities.pm that behaves differently, otherwise the use statement would fail even to find the file* This was the solution to my problem.  An older version of `Utilities.pm` file was taking precedence over the newer one in my `$PERL5LIB` environmental variable, causing Perl to use the wrong module (hence the "missing export" error).

Answer (score 7):

Some people are obsessed with using qw for import lists, even if there is only one element.  I think this makes others think this is a requirement, when it is just one way of making a list.

```
use Foo::Utilities qw('dummy_method');
```

says to import a method called `'dummy_method'`, not `dummy_method`, just like `print qw('dummy_method')` prints `'dummy_method'`, not `dummy_method`.

Try instead:

```
use Foo::Utilities 'dummy_method';
```

or, if you must:

```
use Foo::Utilities qw(dummy_method);
```

Though since you are exporting it by default, you could just do:

```
use Foo::Utilities;
```

Or, since you are calling it as Foo::Utilities::dummy_method, not even export it by default:

```
use Foo::Utilities ();
```

Comment: *"Some people are obsessed with using `qw` for import lists, even if there is only one element"*    Indeed they are, even those here who should know better. I get the idea that it makes it simpler to add to or reduce the list of imported identifiers (which has a parallel in leaving a trailing comma at the end of a list) but it makes the import of a single item much noisier and uglier.

Comment: This is a good suggestion - but in both cases I still get an error saying that the subroutine is not exported from the parent Perl module.

Comment: @alex: Then there is something else wrong with your code that you have removed from what you have posted. There is no way that we can help you.

Comment: Re "*Some people are obsessed with using qw for import lists*", Consistency is key to readable code!

Comment: @ikegami not just readable, it helps you spot bugs from inconsistency.  But, yes.  That's why I *never* use qw for imports, since it looks so silly with just one (and as demonstrated by this question and other anecdotal evidence I've seen, newbies tend to think it is part of the use syntax)

Comment: That's one of the many benefits of readability. :) I don't have a problem with people thinking a great practice is mandatory. I don't think it's any more silly putting parens around one argument to use/import than putting parens around the arguments of anything else. Besides, a bit silliness is trumped by readability every day.